# Oracle - Select multiple aliased rows from dual

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle12c

In Oracle I want to select 2 columns with multiple rows:

Example:

```
name   Phone
----   -----
John   1234
Mary   4321
```

This doesn't work:

```sql
select
   'John' as name,
   'Mary' as name,
   '1234' as phone,
   '4321' as phone
from
   dual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union together two single-row queries:

```
select
   'John' as name,
   '1234' as phone
from
   dual
union all
select
   'Mary' as name,
   '4321' as phone
from
   dual
```

| NAME | PHONE |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1234 |
| Mary | 4321 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=82bf848b2cf4dcd2a0e3a2dadf3bb12a)